# Cannot compile android internal app using Maven

Tags: android, build, maven-3

Im trying to compile the android ics 4.0.4 Phone app using maven. I was able to compile properly using eclipse by adding the required internal jars as system libraries. The required jars were: classes-full-debug.jar from

```
framework_intermediates
android-common_intermediates
guava_intermediates
ext_intermediates
com.android.phone.common_intermediates
com.android.vcard_intermediates
```

of the build.

This is the dependency part of `pom.xml`:

```
`
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.username.ics</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework_intermediates</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.username.ics</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-common_intermediates</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.username.ics</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.android.phone.common_intermediates</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.username.ics</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.android.vcard_intermediates</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.username.ics</groupId>
            <artifactId>ext_intermediates</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.username.ics</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava_intermediates</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
`
```

To compile using Maven, I installed these jars locally using `mvn install:install-file` command as described [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/). Now when I compile, it says some internal classes could not be found. Here is the log:

```
`[INFO] /ssd/packages_app_git/username_ics_packages/apps/Phone/src/com/android/phone/INetworkQueryServiceCallback.aidl:19: couldn't find import for class com.android.internal.telephony.OperatorInfo
[ERROR] Error when generating sources.
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateAidlFiles(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:451)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd /ssd/packages_app_git/username_ics_packages/apps/Phone && /home/username/Dev/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aidl -p/home/username/Dev/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-15/framework.aidl -I/ssd/packages_app_git/username_ics_packages/apps/Phone/target/generated-sources/extracted-dependencies/src/main/java -I/ssd/packages_app_git/username_ics_packages/apps/Phone/src /ssd/packages_app_git/username_ics_packages/apps/Phone/src/com/android/phone/INetworkQueryServiceCallback.aidl /ssd/packages_app_git/username_ics_packages/apps/Phone/target/generated-sources/aidl/com/android/phone/INetworkQueryServiceCallback.java, Result = 1
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$1.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:215)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateAidlFiles(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:449)
    ... 22 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
.
.
.
`
```

The apparently missing `com.android.internal.telephony.OperatorInfo` is there in the framework_intermediates jar. Any ideas on why this could be failing?

Comment: Try to execute failed command in your build environment, sometimes it can give you more information than maven output

Comment: If you mean, put the pom in `packages/apps/Phone` and `mvn install`,  just tried that, its giving the same output. What extra info did you expect it to give?

Comment: No, i mean try to execute in your shell failed command from maven build: /bin/sh -c cd /ssd/packages_app_git/username_ics_packages/apps/Phone && /home/username/Dev/an...

Comment: Thanks. Just tried, it just gave the line number in the file where error occured: `INetworkQueryServiceCallback.aidl:19: couldn't find import for class com.android.internal.telephony.OperatorInfo`.

Comment: The strange thing is, class `OperatorInfo` *is* there inside the framework_intermediates, but is not being picked up by the aidl file. The same import is being used in a java file, `NetworkQueryService.java`, where there is no complaint.

Comment: It just came to my attention: all your dependencies has provided scope, try to play with them

Comment: @TheDimasig: Tried that, to no use. Right now I'm getting around this problem by adding the required `com.android.internal.telephony.OperatorInfo.aidl` file within this package, like how you would do for a normal aidl file. Need to find a proper way to do this.