# Cannot compile system app (Phone) using maven - EventLogTags cannot be resolved

Tags: android, maven, android-source

this is related to my [previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757285/cannot-compile-android-internal-app-using-maven) I'm trying to build `Phone` application from android 4.0.4 using maven (I'm adding framework_intermediates as dependency, so internal apis problems are solved), and I ran into this problem. Some parts of the logs are as follows:

```
Phone/src/com/android/phone/CallNotifier.java:[601,32] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable EventLogTags
```

(the corresponding line in `CallNotifier.java` is: `EventLog.writeEvent(EventLogTags.PHONE_UI_MULTIPLE_QUERY);` )

```
Phone/src/com/android/phone/InCallScreen.java:[723,28] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable EventLogTags
```

(the corresponding line in `InCallScreen.java` is: `EventLog.writeEvent(EventLogTags.PHONE_UI_ENTER);` )

So... it cannot find the class EventLogTags. There is actually a file `Phone/src/com/android/phone/EventLogTags.logtags` which has the following contents:

```
# See system/core/logcat/event.logtags for a description of the format of this file.

option java_package com.android.phone;

70301 phone_ui_enter
70302 phone_ui_exit
70303 phone_ui_button_click (text|3)
70304 phone_ui_ringer_query_elapsed
70305 phone_ui_multiple_query
```

Apparently, this file tells the system to use some particular tags to log important events in the system. I did a full grep, but could not find any file which defines the values `PHONE_UI_ENTER`, `PHONE_UI_MULTIPLE_QUERY`, etc. These are just logs, so I could just comment out these and get it working. But I don't want to do this because I need to build this inside the entire aosp later on. So my question is, how do I get this to compile using maven, without modifying any file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android build system code-generates a Java class out of `.logtags` files if needed. See: https://github.com/android/platform_build/blob/master/core/base_rules.mk

You will need to decipher the `make` rules and run that code generation yourself, I imagine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip man. I tried mmm frameworks/base and I could see that the EventLogTags.java being generated.